# Interpolation of arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, interpolation, curly-braces

A simple question for pros.
 There is a code with which we are getting access to an array value:

```
foreach($basket as $k=>$v)
 echo  "{$v[0]['title']} <br>";



it prints to browser:
 book 1
 book 2
 etc...
```

and now, if we delete the braces such as this:

```
echo  "$v[0]['title'] <br>";
```

it prints:

```
array['title']
array['title']
etc...
```

so interpreter "sees" `$v[0]` and this is an array yes. but he can't get access to `['title']`.

plz tell newbie, why does it happen? i know that braces interpolate a variables in cases when there are some letters around. But there are no letters around here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `echo` first considers `$v[0]` as variable and then prints it's **STRING** value which is **array** and then `['title']` gets interpreted as a plain text string.

Comment: To add: The interpolation "helps" PHP to know which parts it should interpolate. In your first example you are doing it right, you "show" PHP that the whole array/sub array should be interpolated.